# If $a, b$ are two elements of a group such that $ab=ba^{-1}$ and $ba=ab^{-1}$. Show that $ a^4=b^4=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $a, b$ are two elements of a group such that $ab=ba^{-1}$ and $ba=ab^{-1}$. Show that $ a^4=b^4=e$.

Multiplying $ab^2a=e$, i.e $a^2=b^{-2}$.

Also $b^4=ba^2b$ I got such type of relations. How to prove the results.

Comment: $ba^2b=e$ by more or less the same argument as $ab^2a=e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given relations are equivalent to $aba=b$ and $bab=a$, which are easier to work with.

$b^3=b(aba)b=babab$

$\implies b^2=baba=a^2$

$aba=b$

$\implies a^2ba=ab$

$\implies b^2ba=ab$

$\implies b^3a=ab$

$\implies b^4a=bab=a$

$\implies b^4=e$

$\implies a^4=e$ because $a^2=b^2$

Answer (score 2):

Okay so $aba=b $  $bab=a$ So $ababab=ba$. $a^3b=ba$ as $bab=a$. Now $a^3b=a^{-1}b$ again as $aba=b$.Hence done.$a^4=e$.

Answer (score 2):

Regards User..

If you try multiplying $ab$ with $ba$, you would get $ab^{2}a = e$. Then in multiplying in the other order, you would get $ba^{2}b=e$.

Multiply this two in the first way, you would get

$$  (ab^{2}a)(ba^{2}b) = ee= e  $$
But, 
\begin{align*} (ab^{2}a)(ba^{2}b) &= (ab^{2}aba^{2}b) \\
&=  (ab^{2}(ab)a^{2}b) \\
 &= (ab^{2}(ba^{-1})a^{2}b)  \\
&= (ab^{3}ab) \\
&=  (ab^{3}ba^{-1}) = ab^{4}a^{-1} 
\end{align*}

So we get $ ab^{4}a^{-1} = e $. Multiplying by $a^{-1}$ from left and $a$ from right, you would get $b^{4}=e$.

Next, is your turn to prove $$a^{4}= b^{4}=e$$

Thanks.