# $a^{-1}\star b \star a = b^{-1}$ and $b^{-1} \star a \star b = a^{-1}$ Then $a^4=e=b^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are elements of the group $(G, \star)$ such that $$a^{-1}\star b \star a = b^{-1}$$ and $$b^{-1} \star a \star b = a^{-1}$$ Then $a^4=e=b^4$

I tried to prove it like this:

Based on the thing we got we have:

$$a= b^{-1}a^{-1}b$$
and
$$b= a^{-1}b^{-1}a$$
And the I thought about this that $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=bb^{-1}=b^{-1}b=e$.

Then I tried for example $aa^{-1}=b^{-1}b$. This means that
$$b^{-1}a^{-1}bb^{-1}ab=a^{-1}baa^{-1}b^{-1}a$$.
But it doesn't answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222709/if-a-b-are-two-elements-of-a-group-such-that-ab-ba-1-and-ba-ab-1-s

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you